# MediaWiki authentication with credentials of a Windows domain

Tags: php, windows, iis, single-sign-on, mediawiki

I wish to create a wiki page for internal use within my company.

Ideally, I would like it to verify logins against our company windows domain, so that the user does not have to create a new account specifically for the wiki in order to to access it.

So, users currently log into a domain when they log into their computer in work in the morning. I want to use these credentials in my webpage to verify that the user should be allowed to edit the page ? I want the users login to be maintained so that we can keep track of who makes the edits and when.

Is it possible to do this ? What can I do to make this change ?

Comment: Does this work for you? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication

Comment: @tubaguy50035 many thanks for the response. I had seen this; but configuring this to work within an enterprise seems incredibly confusing! See here : http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication/Configuration

Comment: Maybe checkout this? http://www.librarywebchic.net/2006/04/20/wikiperiments/  Walks through it in a more step by step approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) or [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) will allow you to do single sign on with an Active Directory storing Windows domain credentials. Check out the [MediaWiki authentication extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aUser_identity_extensions). Particularly, the [Kerberos configuration for the LDAP Authentication extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication/Kerberos_Configuration_Examples) or [this NTLM extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWindows_NTLM_LDAP_Auto_Auth).